# iOS Widevine with Xamarin

Tags: hyperlink, xamarin, wrapper, widevine

I am needing to use the widevine api in an ios app written in xamarin. From what I understand I need to make a wrapper for the library and such, but I have no idea where to start. Can anyone either explain in more detail what to do, or point me somewhere that explains it well?

Thanks, I am quite new to Xamarin, and rusty on C#

Comment: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/Walkthrough_Binding_objective-c_library/

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but this tutorial seems to indicate you need access to the Widevine iOS project inorder to do the binding. All I have is the .a file. Am I wrong, or missing something?

Comment: No you just need the library.  The first part of the walkthrough explains how to build a library from source, but if you already have the compiled library you can start with the 2nd part.

Comment: By second part do you mean starting at the 'Create a Xamarin.iOS Binding Project'?

Comment: Yes.  There is a whole section of docs on Binding in addition to the Walkthrough.

Comment: Ok, thank you. The part that confuses me is using Objective Sharpie. The bind command required access to the library's xcode project header files.

Comment: Generally C based libraries have to include header files in order to interface with them.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to follow [Jason's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31884984/ios-widevine-with-xamarin#comment51688194_31884984). In short, you need the .a (fat library) and the header files and then create a Xamarin.iOS binding project that exposes the native interface to C#. Access to the source code is not necessary.